# Out Of Memory - C Interpreter Error - Ideas?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, loadrunner

So I am having issues with getting C interpreter errors -  memory violation when running the script on most of our load generators. We have a couple server 2003(8gb ram) load generators that the script runs fine on. However all of the windows 7 machines (4gb ram) will not run the script. My first inclination is that its just running out of memory, however when I watch the resources on the 2003 server when its running it increases only 200mb of memory when I run the script.

What the script does: It reads a file into memory, that buffer is then assigned to a LR parameter, that parameter is then assigned to an attachment of a MTOM SOAP request. When using small files 20mb and below I can run it in VUgen, larger files such as 85mb, I get Memory Access Violation. I then have to run it through performance center, using the 2003 Server Load Generator, which it runs and executes fine.

Since it runs on the machine with more memory I would have thought it was more due to memory available, yet when the script runs, not much is used on the 2003 server LG.

Any insight on this would be great!

Code:

```
#define SEEK_SET 0 /* beginning of file. */
#define SEEK_CUR 1 /* current position. */
#define SEEK_END 2   /* end of file */

int requestPrepared = 0;
 char *filename2 = "test.gz";

setEXTERNALfile()
{
 long infile; // file pointer
 char *buffer; // buffer to read file contents into
 //Old Code
 //char *filename = "C:\\EPD\\INDIVIDUAL\\XML\\EPDIndividual_1.xml"; // file to read. old code.
 //Old code
 char *filenumber[15];
 int fileLen; // file size
 int newfileLen; // New file size
 int fileSizeSub; //linix file si
 int bytesRead; // bytes read from file

 char newfilename[40]; //contains file name path
 char *fileext = ".xml"; // ext of file to read

 typedef void *gzFile;
 gzFile file;

  int count;

 //char *filenumber2[40];
 char filename[155];
 char fileDirectory[155];

 sprintf(fileDirectory, "%s", lr_eval_string("{pFileDirectory}"));
 lr_output_message("Current fileDirectory %s", lr_eval_string("{pFileDirectory}"));

 sprintf(filename, "%s", lr_eval_string("{pFileName}"));

//  80 MB file
 sprintf(newfilename,"\\\\LOCATION\\%s\\%s%s", fileDirectory, filename, fileext);

 // open the file
 infile = fopen(newfilename, "rb");
 if (!infile) {
   lr_error_message("Unable to open file %s", newfilename);
   return;
 }


 // get the file length
 fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
 fileLen=ftell(infile);
 newfileLen=ftell(infile)+2;
 fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_SET);
 lr_log_message("File length is: %9d bytes.", fileLen);
 lr_save_int(newfileLen,"pNewFileSize");
 lr_log_message("New File length is: %9d bytes.", newfileLen);


 // Allocate memory for buffer to read file
 buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
 if (!buffer) {
   lr_error_message("Could not malloc %10d bytes", fileLen+1);
   fclose(infile);
   return;
 }


 // Read file contents into buffer
 bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, fileLen, infile);
 if (bytesRead != fileLen) 
 {
   lr_error_message("File length is %10d bytes but only read %10d bytes", fileLen, bytesRead);
 }
 else
 {
   lr_log_message("Successfully read %9d bytes from file: ", bytesRead);
 }
 fclose(infile);


 // Save the buffer to a loadrunner parameter
 lr_save_var( buffer, bytesRead, 0, "fileDataParameter");
 free(buffer);
 //lr_log_message("File contents: %s", lr_eval_string("{fileDataParameter}"));
```

Comment: How many virtual users are reading this from disk and then into a buffer in RAM? 85MB times how many?

Comment: Hey James. We are running one virtual user per LG. One VU reads a single file, so its set up as unique param, just so there is no collision.

Comment: You do realise that without a type specified functions default to returning `int`? Should really specify `void`.

Comment: Bump... Notify: Saving Parameter "pNewFileSize = 87338479".
File length is:  87338479 bytes.
Successfully read  87338477 bytes from file: 
Error: Failed to allocate memory of size: 349353908 for sending message to log file

Comment: FYI the reason for adding the two bytes is we are transferring the file from a windows machine to a linux machine. Windows reads the file size smaller as it doesnt read the CTLF, as Linux counts that.

Comment: Turn down your log level.  It should be as low as possible during testing to avoid bottlenecks in the file system

Comment: Yep Logging is turned off.

Comment: Is there a better way of saving this param? I notice that saving it to a LR param seems to times the memory used by 4... `// Save the buffer to a loadrunner parameter lr_save_var( buffer, bytesRead, 0, "fileDataParameter"); free(buffer);`

Comment: See help for `web_custom_request` and search for `raw body` in the help. Use that to specify a binary buffer in memory, eliminating the need to store the data as a LR variable. Also maybe `BodyFilePath` could be useful..